# How is the Lie derivative of the metric wrt a gradient field twice the Hessian?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ and $f \in C^\infty(M)$. Denote by $\operatorname{grad} f$ the gradient of $f$, i.e. the vector field on $M$ such that for any other vector field $X$, $g(\operatorname{grad} f, X) = df(X)=X(f)$. Then, if $L_{Y}$ denotes the Lie derivative with respect to the vector field $Y$, how is it that $L_{\operatorname{grad} f}g = 2\operatorname{Hess}(f) := 2\nabla \nabla f$?

Comment: Do you know how the Lie derivative acts on arbitrary tensor fields?

Comment: @Chris, yes, as described on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative.